# Builiding a booking mern project with cookie based authentication deployed succesfully, even though got other user details in res but cookie not?

Tags: reactjs, express

done the all settings for samesite , secure , using the credentials true , and while with req from the client doing it with withcredentails true , but cookie is not there

my server.js and index.js
--index.js

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import hotelRouter from './routers/hotel.route.js'
import userRouter from './routers/user.route.js'
import authRouter from './routers/auth.route.js'
import roomRouter from './routers/rooms.route.js'
import bookingrouter from './routers/booking.route.js'

import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import ErrorHandler from './utils/ErrorHandler.js'
dotenv.config()

export const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser())


//middleware
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://waneem-admin.onrender.com",
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: true,
    methods: "*"
}))
app.set("trust proxy", 1)

app.use(express.json())
//router
app.use('/api/v1/auth', authRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/hotels', hotelRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/room', roomRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/booking', bookingrouter)


app.use('/api/v1/user', userRouter)

const toke = "Sdfsdfsd"
app.get(
    '/api/v1', (req, res) => {
        console.log(toke)
        console.log('here')
        res.status(200).cookie("access_token", toke, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true
        }).send('hello from express')
        console.log(res)
    }


)
console.log(process.env.ADMIN_URL, process.env.CLIENT_URL)


//error middleware

app.use(ErrorHandler)
```

--server.js

```
import { app } from './index.js'
import connectDB from './database.js'



app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
    connectDB()

    console.log("listening on port 3000")
})
```

..auth controller

```
import User from "../models/user.model.js"
import CreateError from "../utils/CreateError.js"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import { Sendtoken } from "../utils/Sendtoken.js"


export const register = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { password, isAdmin, ...data } = req.body;
        let isadmin = false;

        // Verify the token
        const token = req.cookies.access_token;



        if (token) {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            if (decoded && decoded.isAdmin) {
                isadmin = req.body.isAdmin || false;
            }
        }

        // Check if a user with the same email already exists
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: data.email });
        if (existingUser) {
            return next(CreateError(400, `User with email ${data.email} already exists`));
        }

        // Hash the password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

        // Create a new user
        const user = new User({
            ...data,
            password: hashedPassword,
            isAdmin: isadmin,
        });

        // Save the user
        await user.save();

        // Generate and send the token
        Sendtoken(user, res, 200, "User registered successfully", next);
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

---sendtoken.js

```
import CreateError from "./CreateError.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"

export const Sendtoken = async (user, res, statusCode = 200, message, next) => {


    try {
        const token = await jwt.sign({ id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1d" })

        return res.status(statusCode).cookie("access_token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true
        }).json({
            success: true,
            message: message || 'login successfull',
            user: user

        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return next(err)
    }




}
```

--my fronedn client side

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react"
import { Authcontext } from "../../context/Authcontext.jsx"
import axios from "axios"
import "./Login.scss"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
const Login = () => {

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email: undefined,
    password: undefined,
  })
  const { currentUser, loading, error, dispatch } = useContext(Authcontext)
  const handlechange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    return setCredentials((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    }))
  }
  ///code for make user go back on same page after login from where he is reidirected

  console.log(loading)
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const handlesubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("handlesubmit")
    console.log("here")

    dispatch({ type: "START" })
    try {
      const { email, password } = credentials
      const res = await axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_SERVER_URL}/api/v1/auth/login`, {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
      dispatch({ type: "SUCCESS", payload: res?.data?.user })
      navigate('/')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, "by here this error")
      dispatch({ type: "FAILURE", payload: err.response.data.message })
    }
  }

  return (
    <form className="login" onSubmit={handlesubmit} autoComplete="new-password">
      <div className="loginwrapper">
        <h1> Login</h1>
        <input
          className="logininput"
          placeholder="username"
          type="email"
          id="email"
          value={credentials.email}
          onChange={handlechange}
        />
        <input
          className="logininput"
          placeholder="password"
          type="password"
          autoComplete="new-password"
          id="password"
          value={credentials.password}
          onChange={handlechange}
        />
        <button disabled={loading} className="btn" type="submit">
          submit
        </button>
        {error && <span className="error"> {error}</span>}
        <div className="form-bottom">
          <span className="forgot">Forgot Password?</span>
          <span className=" registerbtn" onClick={() => navigate('/register')}>Register here</span></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default Login
```

client url -------https://waneem-admin.onrender.com/--
---------for more reference server(https://github.com/wakai-megumi/waneem__Server)
--------for client side code (https://github.com/wakai-megumi/waneem__admin) ..plenty of days with the issue